# Slideshow not centering?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have a slideshow that I wanted to center, but I can't center it properly, the left part of the image stands exacly in the middle, so the image is not centered, anyone has an idea why?

Here's the following code and images:

***CSS***

```
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height:400px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.slider-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin:auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}
```

`.slider` contains: `.slider-wrapper` and `.slide`, `.slide` is the class I use for each image.

***HTML***

```
<div class="slider" id="main-slider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <img src="images/eventos/image1.png" class="slide" />
            <img src="images/eventos/image2.png" class="slide" />
            <img src="images/eventos/image3.png" class="slide" />
            <img src="images/eventos/image4.png" class="slide" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This image contains `text-align:center` and `margin: 0 auto`

[image]

And this one doens't

[image]

My code contains jquery so the slideshow works, if needed, please ask so I put it in too.

### UPDATE

I discovered the problem, the problem is the `position: absolute` in those images, I deleted every css and any div I had and left the the `.slide` and just the images, in `.slide` I just left `position: absolute` and it still didn't work, so what can I do?

Comment: Do you have any padding inside the slider perhaps?

Comment: Hint: you could make this into a perfect [mcve] by turning it into a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @MilanVelebit All the styling is there

Comment: Is your images taking the full width ??

Comment: @Ashishsah The images don't have full width, they just ocuppy that area, no margin, no padding. Read the update and see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply `text-align:center` alignment on a absolute positioned element. Remove the absolute position and the images should center when using text-align in your wrapper:

```
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height:400px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.slider-wrapper{
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms linear;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

However, It is unclear from your code whether the absolute position is required. If so, you may need to resort to js calculations.

**UPDATE**

From OP comment, position absolute is required. Therefore, it is necessary to set the `left` attribute on slides. If the slide width is known, you could calculate by subtracting half of the viewport width from half of the slide width. For instance, on a 200px wide slide:

```
left:calc(50vw - 100px);
```

Assuming slides have variable width, resort to js:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('foo');
var width = myElement.offsetWidth;
myElement.style.left = 'calc(50vw - ' + width / 2 + 'px)';
```

In lieu of finding elements by id, requiring individual ids for each slide, you may want to store all slides in an object array using `getElementsByClassName('slide')` and retrieving the width according to the  slide currently displayed.

Comment: The `position: absolute` is needed because the images are above each other, so when the next slide appears, one fades away and the other appears. Without it, the animation would bug and look ugly.

Comment: You can indeed use `margin: 0 auto` on an absolutely positioned element: https://jsfiddle.net/u18tp03q/

Comment: @jfeferman I just learned that trick not too long ago myself =) Figured I'd share.

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho please review my update to the answer.

Comment: @jfeferman That worked quite well! But if the image is big enought to cover the whole div, will there be bugs? And also, how do I center from top and bottom? Same thing but with height and top?

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho if the image is larger than the container, the result of the calculation will be a negative left position, which should be ok as it will still center. Another note, please consider that `50vw` is half of the viewport width. You might wish to use `50%` instead, to obtain half the width of the container.

Comment: @jfeferman Thank you, I tried by myself to the the top part and It worked! But I have a problem, it's only changing the next images, not all

Comment: It would be helpful if you place your full code in a jsfiddle. This way its possible to debug the js. Also, check out @DanielD's solution below. It might be a simpler fix.

Comment: @jfeferman https://jsfiddle.net/2mau3a2s/ It doesn't work when I put it on fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center an element that is set to `position: absolute`, you need to set the `left` and `right` properties to `0`. I.e. `right: 0` and `left: 0`. Check out the code below:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    transition: opacity 500ms linear;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height:400px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.slider-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    transition: opacity 500ms linear;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="main-slider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <img src="images/eventos/image1.png" class="slide" />
            <img src="images/eventos/image2.png" class="slide" />
            <img src="images/eventos/image3.png" class="slide" />
            <img src="images/eventos/image4.png" class="slide" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `position: fixed;` and then `top: 50%; left: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was controlling the width of the of the direct children of the class `uk-slider-items` through `uk-child-width-1-3@m` as follows:

```
<div class="uk-container">
<h1 class="uk-heading-line uk-text-center uk-padding-large"><span>Similar Products</span></h1>

<div uk-slider="center: true">

    <div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light">

        <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-2 uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-child-width-1-3@m uk-grid uk-grid-match"  >

            <li v-for="(pro,index) in category"  :key="index">
                <div class="uk-card uk-card-default">
                    <div class="uk-card-media-top">
                        <img src="/product.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-card-body">
                        <h3 class="uk-card-title">{{pro.name}}</h3>
                        <p>{{pro.details}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-background-secondary" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
        <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-background-secondary" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>

    </div>

    <ul class="uk-slider-nav uk-dotnav uk-flex-center uk-margin"></ul>

</div>
```